# Upgrading Angular application to Bootstrap 4.0.0

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I upgrade my existing angular application to Bootstrap version 4.0.0.

I know it would be easy but I am looking for proper process to upgrade without facing much issues as I could see many stack overflows of Bootstrap 4.0.0 Stable bugs.

Thanks,

Comment: `npm install bootstrap@latest` works with Angular 7, just tried it. I got Bootstrap [4.3.1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My take is:

1. delete the node_modules folder (just in case)
2. delete the bootstrap entries from the package.jsons
3. `npm i bootstrap` to install [bootstrap4](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap)
4. install ng-bootstrap via the [offical guide](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started): `npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using yarn

```
yarn upgrade bootstrap@latest
```

Answer (score 1):

```
npm update --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

This will update your current bootstrap package to lastest version. And then run

```
npm audit fix
```